# How to acquire MD5 fingerprint from Mavericks

Tags: android, md5, osx-mavericks, fingerprint

I am new to developing android apps.  I am currently attempting to incorporate some Google maps into my android app.  I have been using some tutorials that say I need the MD5 fingerprint from my local machine in order to get the API key, but I do not know how to get this MD5 fingerprint.  Can any one assist or can point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Write in terminal :

```
keytool -list -storepass android -keystore /Users/sigrlami/.android/debug.keystore
```

you need to locate your debug.keystore first

It will return *Certificate fingerprint (MD5)* like this: C0:DC:2A:E4:E6:C6:C2:93:CF:9E:xxxxxxx.....